# How to fill a listbox based on Environment.ProcessorCount

Tags: wpf

I want to fill a listbox/combobox with values like "CPU 1", "CPU 2", etc.

The number of items will be equal to Environment.ProcessorCount.

I know the approach with user controls and C# programming, but i want this all in XAML. would you please show me some directions or provide some samples ?

Thx in Adv

Answer (score 2):

You will have to some some form of code behind/VM to do this. You can't do all in xaml.

I would:

1. Create a view model class
2. Create a property on that class which is some form of `IEnumerable<string>`. Using an `ObservableCollection<string>` here might be overkill given that people don't tend to have the number of processors change at all.
3. When the view model instance is instantiated, generate your strings (ie. `for(var i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount; ++i) { CpuList.Add(string.Format("CPU {0}", i + 1)); }`
4. Bind your XAML to this view model property `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CpuList}" />` after setting the DataSource for the list or parent window to the view model instance: `someWindow.DataContext = new ViewModelClass();`

Doneski!